# Problema com numeração de páginas com CSS na visualização de impressão

Tags: html, css, table

Tenho um relatório onde são criadas várias tabelas separadas por categorias com cabeçalho e rodapé específicos que se repetem.

Preciso adicionar uma numeração de páginas para as categorias onde em cada nova categoria essa numeração seja reiniciada e por conta da variação de tamanho e do número de linhas acaba impossibilitando fazer essa contagem via back-end.

Para resolver essa situação pensei em utilizar os contadores "Counters" de CSS para a contagem de páginas. Só que encontrei um problema na visualização de impressão, já que não dá pra determinar quantas vezes o cabeçalho ou rodapé irá se repetir para fazer essa contagem de páginas.

Na visualização da impressão não está incrementando o número de páginas conforme o cabeçalho da tabela. Tentei utilizar no CSS @Page para fazer o incremento das páginas e usar o counter-reset em cada tabela para que a numeração fosse reiniciada, mas o problema mesmo é incrementar a numeração de páginas conforme a categoria.

```css
CSS

.report-table {
  page-break-after: always;
  counter-reset: page;
}

.report-header {
  display: table-header-group;
}

.report-header tr th span.page-number:after {
  counter-increment: page;
  content: "Pag:" counter(page);
}

.report-footer {
  display: table-footer-group;
}
```

```html
HTML

<button onclick="window.print();">Print</button>
<table class="report-table">
  <thead class="report-header">
    <tr>
      <th>conteudo</th>
      <th>conteudo</th>
      <th><span class="page-number"></span></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tfoot class="report-footer">
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>valor</td>
      <td>$ 0,00 </td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>conteudo</td>
      <td>conteudo</td>
      <td>conteudo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>tabela</td>
      <td>longa</td>
      <td>aqui</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>conteudo</td>
      <td>conteudo</td>
      <td>conteudo</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

JSFiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/7prs03eh/2/

Comment: Esse artigo deve te interessar. https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2015/01/designing-for-print-with-css/ leia em "PAGE BREAKS" e "Counters" que deve ter o que vc precisa

Comment: Excelente o artigo! Com certeza será bem útil, mas infelizmente ele ainda não resolve a situação da pergunta. O problema acontece na visualização da impressão (fiz o edit para corrigir isso). A contagem de páginas conforme a repetição do cabeçalho não acontece já que ele parece ser criado apenas uma vez, mesmo sendo repetido várias vezes na visualização da impressão.

Comment: Vc pode ter vários títulos de sessão, mesmo que iguais, mas que só vão aparecer no @-print. no @-screen vc deixa eles ocultos com display:none, só da display:block no css de impressão @print. Para cara título desses que vai aparecer vc usa o page-break para iniciar cara título em uma página diferente, e coloca um counter para cada título desses. Se o sistema for pequeno pode resolver, mas se for muito grande essa dinâmica pode ser inviável.